# Restoring mongodb from archived dumb on S3 server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, openshift, database-restore, dumb-data

I'm having a mongodb deployed on openshift, I want to restore the data from S3 bucket, is there a way to do this directly or I need to download the data from S3 first and then run `mongorestore` command?

Comment: you need to download it first and run mongo restore